# EdgeRouter Lite OpenBSD traffic routing limits

Tags: performance, firewall, openbsd, vlan, pf

When routing traffic between (virtual) interfaces on [Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite](https://openwrt.org/toh/ubiquiti/edgerouter_lite) it is hitting some sort of limit. I'd like to get some help to determine what sort of limit is that and how it can be addressed. This is on a home network.

The EdgeRouter Lite is dual core router with Cavium CPU at 500MHz. It is currently running OpenBSD 6.9, using the `GENERIC.MP` kernel (the [octeon](https://www.openbsd.org/octeon.html) architecture).

There is a Gigabit Netgear GS108Ev3 switch connected to one port of the router. The switch is configured with multiple VLANs. The switch is connected to the router using trunk port. When transferring data using rsync over SSH, uploading data from Mac mini (Intel Core-i5 with internal SSD) host in one VLAN to a Raspberry 4 (2 GB RAM, WD USB 4TB disk connected via USB-3) in another VLAN, this negatively impacts traffic on different VLAN that is going also through the router (e.g. WiFI VLAN clients connecting through the router to the internet), for instance when said rsync transfer is active, DNS lookup latencies go up significantly, sometimes causing smartphones to disconnect from the WiFi (the WiFI AP is another VLAN on the same switch), thinking the WiFi network is not capable of handling traffic. The upload traffic on the mac mini when the rsync is running is cca 11 MB/s. Both the Mac mini and the Raspberry Pi report the Ethernet speed to be 1 Gbit.

Looking at the CPU utilization on the router with `top`, it varies. Sometimes the `sys` load is spread across the 2 CPU cores, sometimes just one CPU core is loaded (92% `sys` utilization).

The router has a set of PF rules in place. There is a Grafana dashboard collecting metrics from the router and the 'PF actions' panel reports some 19 K rule search operations happening per second (averaged over 5 minutes), the rate of state insertions/deletions is negligible. The graph tops at 19K when the rsync is running. When I stop the rsync, the rate goes down to hundreds of state searches. Also, the SSH CLI handling on the router also becomes much more responsive once again.

I went through the changelogs for both OpenBSD 7.0 and 7.1 and did not notice any MP related improvements that seem like they could help.

For each SSH connection from the Mac mini to the Raspberry Pi, there are 2 PF states on the router (one for each direction), corresponding to the following rules:

```
# allow internal net to connect anywhere
pass in quick on $InnerIF from $Internal_net to any

# allow internal net to access TCP services on the Raspberry Pi host
pass out quick on $CLDIF inet proto tcp \
        from $Internal_net to $docker \
        keep state
```

The interfaces in the rules are `vlanXY` interfaces.

Checking the output of `pfctl -si`, I don't see any hints of too low memory or such. `top` reports some 80 MB of free RAM.

Is there some tuning I can do or is this the case where buying a new router with [more performant CPU](https://kernelpanic.life/hardware/openbsd-router-benchmarks.html) (such as [Edgerouter 4](https://openwrt.org/toh/ubiquiti/edgerouter_4) with 1 GHz quad-core CPU) is in order ?

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly I have an EdgeRouter Lite running OpenBSD 7.1 (with [a bridge setup](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Bridge)), and a newer Mac Mini with macOS, and some other machines talking over the router. Using the default `pf` rules on the router, I can't say that the router is slowing down the traffic compared to connecting the other machines to the Mac Mini via an unmanaged ZAP Gigabit switch.

Comment: The bridge processing is probably different than inter-VLAN routing. I've since revised the PF ruleset a bit, specifically the scrub rules that applied to all interfaces in both directions to just `match in on $ExtIF all scrub (reassemble tcp)`, however it did not cause any difference.

Comment: upgraded to 7.0, not much difference - it seems little bit more responsive with one rsync in progress, however when 2 rsync streams are running, the connect timeouts strike again. The mac mini reports the traffic at 13 MB/s.

Comment: For the record, my Edgerouter Lite died this week. I replaced it with Edgerouter 4 (lucky to get one second hand) and updated to OpenBSD 7.2 that had significant networking changes w.r.t. parallelization of data path, I believe. scp'ing a file across VLANs to the same RPi 4 as described above with spinning drive can get 33 MB/s reliably and the 4-core router is chugging along, with 2 cores utilized with 33% and 25% respectively, the other 2 cores idle.